# what will be value stored in DB indexes?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I understand that relational DB's like mysql uses hashmap or B+trees for indexing. What will be the value stored in B+tree ? is it hash value of the  keys for which indexes are created ? or the key value itself ?

Comment: It's the key itself. It doesn't make sense to store a hash value in a B-tree.

Comment: Jus wanted to understand better . In case if the key is VARCHAR index(B+tree) will be created with that much big size ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's talk `ENGINE=InnoDB` only.

Indexes are BTrees; there are no Hash indexes, nor hashed strings.  (There are also `FULLTEXT` and `SPATIAL`.)

The data is in a BTree ordered by the `PRIMARY KEY`.  We say that the PK is "clustered".

Each "secondary key" is in a separate BTree, ordered by the key column(s).  In the leaf is a copy of the PK, so that it can reach over to get the rest of the columns.

Aside from overhead, an `INT` takes 4 bytes in the index; a `VARCHAR` takes enough space for the text, plus a 1- or 2- byte length.  Etc.

Yes, typically a `VARCHAR` is bulkier than an `INT`.  But that is not  necessarily  bad.  For example, if you have a "natural" PK that is `VARCHAR`, there may (or may not) be justification for instead creating an `INT AUTO_INCREMENT` as the PK.  Show me an example `CREATE TABLE`; I will critique the indexes.